# how to use jsonschema validation in angular js/rest web service architecture?

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am looking to design a client-side json validator through a json schema created for a server (Java backend), so it is important that I use the same schema. What plugins are useful for angularjs to implement json validation on the client?

Comment: joi runs in the browser, and I like it quite a bit.

Comment: @JoshC - the question used the "jsonschema" tag, so I assume they meant the actual [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/), which Joi doesn't appear to use.

Comment: [tv4](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tv4) is pretty popular, runs in the browser, etc.  (Disclaimer: my project).  Don't know how Angular validation works, though...

Comment: @cloudfeet "What plugins are useful for angular js to implement jsonvalidation on the client?" led me to think the OP was willing to consider something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following angular plugin. It provides a directive to build forms out of JSON Schemas. The schemas can be loaded via a http-service. https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form!